# Extracting text from each PDF page using pdfminer.six

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, pdfminer

The documentation for pdfminer is poor at best. I was initially using pdfminer and had it working for some PDF files then I ran into some bugs and realized I should be using pdfminer.six

I want to extract the text from each page of the PDF so that way I can keep tabs on where I found specific words and such.

Using the documentation:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice

# Open a PDF file.
fp = open('mypdf.pdf', 'rb')
# Create a PDF parser object associated with the file object.
parser = PDFParser(fp)
# Create a PDF document object that stores the document structure.
# Supply the password for initialization.
document = PDFDocument(parser, password)
# Check if the document allows text extraction. If not, abort.
if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
# Create a PDF resource manager object that stores shared resources.
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
# Create a PDF device object.
device = PDFDevice(rsrcmgr)
# Create a PDF interpreter object.
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
# Process each page contained in the document.
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
```

We've parsed all the pages but there is no documentation on how to get what elements or anything from the PDFpage

I looked though the PDFPage.py file for a way to extract the text from each PDF page and of course it's not that simple.

To complicate matters theres at least 3 versions of pdfminer and of course over time things have been upgraded so any examples I can find are not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version I'm using for extracting text from pdf files.

```
import io
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage


def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    """
    This function extracts text from pdf file and return text as string.
    :param pdf_path: path to pdf file.
    :return: text string containing text of pdf.
    """
    resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle)
    page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

    # close open handles
    converter.close()
    fake_file_handle.close()

    if text:
        return text
    return None
```

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately. I am using pdfminer.six in Python 3